# How to properly call Wolframscript from Python?

Tags: scripting, python

I am using Windows 10 x64.

If I run the following code in Command Prompt:

```
wolframscript -code ToString[TeXForm["Integrate[Tan[x],x]"]]
```

I get the following output (note the extra newline):

```
-\log (\cos (x))
```

If I run the following code in Python 3.8.2:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('wolframscript -code ToString[TeXForm["Integrate[Tan[x],x]"]]')
```

I get the following output:

```
-\log (\cos (x))
CompletedProcess(args='wolframscript -code ToString[TeXForm["Integrate[Tan[x],x]"]]', returncode=3)
```

For some reason, the return code is 3 instead of 0 so calling wolframscript with subprocess.check_output raises an exception instead of giving me the output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'wolframscript -code ToString[TeXForm["Integrate[Tan[x],x]"]]' returned non-zero exit status 3.
```

EDIT:
I found a solution:

```
 subprocess.run('wolframscript -code ToString[TeXForm["Integrate[Tan[x],x]"]]', capture_output=True).stdout.decode().rstrip()
```

but that return code is still bugging me.

Notes for my "solution" to my future self:

1. I added the argument `capture_output=True` to the `subprocess.run` function:

   ```
   subprocess.run('wolframscript -code ...', capture_output=True)
   ```
2. With that set, the output will be saved to a variable called `stdout` so we can access it.

   ```
   subprocess.run(' ... ', capture_output=True).stdout
   ```
3. The variable `stdout` contains the output in a "raw" format i.e. `b'output'` so we decode it to a python string via the `decode()` method:

   ```
   subprocess.run(' ... ', capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
   ```
4. Finally, remove the newline with the `rstrip()` method:

   ```
   subprocess.run(' ... ', capture_output=True).stdout.decode().rstrip()
   ```

Comment: I have to imagine that [this client library](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) would be helpful.